# How to detect whether a specific font shape exists

Tags: xetex, fontspec

I am using the font Times New Roman as the main font in my document class. The font works fine under Windows, but fails to display small captital font shape under macOS. It turns out that the relative older version that comes with macOS (`5.01.3x` compared to `7.00` under Windows) does not imbed the smcp feature.

The problem is then how to warn the user beforehand if the smcp feature is missing, and automatically substitute the main font as TeX Gyre Termes. As far as I know, the `fontspec` package I am using for XeLaTeX does not provide an explicit API for such function. Meanwhile I haved traced down the kernal warning in `source2e` to `\wrong@fontshape`, but unaware of how this can be adapted, with my limited understanding :(

I will be very much appreciated for any help provided.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `fontspec` package provides the function `\fontspec_if_small_caps:TF` to check whether the current font has small caps (either as a feature, or as a separate font face), as well as `\fontspec_if_feature:nTF` to test for an arbitrary OpenType feature, such as `smcp`,  These are documented in section 5.3 of the `fontspec` manual, and require `\ExplSyntaxOn`.

An alternative is to load TeX Gyre Termes, a clone of Times that every TeX distribution includes, and which does contain small caps.  On a correctly-configured system with the `tex-gyre` package installed, `\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}` should just work (but some distributions are not correctly configured out of the box).

You could also load this font for small caps only with the `SmallCapsFont` option, documented in section 4.1 of the `fontspec` manual.  If you really, truly want to mix Times New Roman with TeX Gyre Termes this way, here is how:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}[
  UprightFeatures = {SmallCapsFont = texgyretermes-regular.otf,
                     SmallCapsFeatures = {Letters=SmallCaps, Scale=MatchUppercase}},
  BoldFeatures = {SmallCapsFont = texgyretermes-bold.otf,
                  SmallCapsFeatures = {Letters=SmallCaps, Scale=MatchUppercase}},
  ItalicFeatures = {SmallCapsFont = texgyretermes-italic.otf,
                    SmallCapsFeatures = {Letters=SmallCaps, Scale=MatchUppercase}},
  BoldItalicFeatures = {SmallCapsFont = texgyretermes-bolditalic.otf,
                        SmallCapsFeatures = {Letters=SmallCaps, Scale=MatchUppercase}}
]

\begin{document}
\noindent
Regular \textsc{Small Caps}\\
\textbf{Bold \textsc{Small Caps}}\\
\textit{Italic \textsc{Small Caps}}\\
\textit{\textbf{Bold Italic \textsc{Small Caps}}}
\end{document}
```

[image: Times New Roman + TeX Gyre Termes sample]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your timely aid! I must apologize for my failure to check the manual throughly. It is also worth mentioning that I have also tried the solution in section 4.1. However, `fontspec` failed to load `TeX Gyre Termes` by its family name with the newly installed MacTeX on the machine that I was testing. I think this problem does not bother any more providing your answer, though.

Comment: I haven’t tried MacTeX, but make sure the TeX Gyre fonts are installed. I’ve added a better MWE.